# Java Format Specifier for Limiting Trailing Zeros to 1

Tags: java, format

I'm looking for a format specifier to limit the number of trailing zeros after a decimal to just 1, but if they aren't all zeros then truncate to two.

Like so:

```
127.000000 -> 127.0

0.000000 -> 0.0

123.456 -> 123.45
```

I Have tried taking care of it with logic but it doesn't seem to work.

call my number `result` and use the following logic:

```
    if(result - (int)result == 0){
        output = String.format("%.1f\n",result);
    }
    else{
        output = String.format("%.2f\n,result);
    }
```

sometimes this logic works, and sometimes it doesnt. For example

`(int)result - result == 0`  is `true` for `0.000000`

but `false` for `127.000000`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered doing this with string manipulation, taking a string with extra trailing zeroes and removing them there, rather than changing the format string?

Comment: Why are you saying `int(result) - result == 0` gives `false` for result = 127.00000f? It should be true.

Comment: @jrook it is false in my environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want at most two digits after the decimal point, you can first cut the rest out and then decide if you want to keep the last digit or not.

```
    float result = 127.8901f; //0.0000 
    String output = String.format("%.2f", result);
    if (output.endsWith("00")) output = output.substring(0,output.length()-1);
```

Comment: What about the case that it ends with just "0" and not "00" ?

Comment: The OP says ending with one zero is acceptable. At least with the 3 cases they have indicated, this seems to work. Do you have a test case that fails?

Comment: I see. Isn't there a better solution though?

Answer (score 5):

What about `NumberFormat`?

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ROOT);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String s1 = formatter.format(127.000000);
String s2 = formatter.format(0.000000);
String s3 = formatter.format(123.456);
System.out.println(s1);     //prints 127.0
System.out.println(s2);     //prints 0.0
System.out.println(s3);     //prints 123.46
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to string and look for `.` index

```
    String n1 = new String("127.000000");
    String output=null;

    if(n1.charAt(n1.indexOf(".")+2)>'0') //after decimal if non-zero at second position
    {
        output= n1.substring(0,n1.indexOf(".")+3);
    }
    else
    {
        output= n1.substring(0,n1.indexOf(".")+2);  
    }

    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regex that works:

```
public class DecimalTest {

private static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.)(0|\\d\\d)");
private static final String[] TEST_VALUES = {"127.000000", "0.0000000", "123.456"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (final String testValue : TEST_VALUES) {
        final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(testValue);
        if (matcher.find())
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late from the party now 5 and a half years later, but someone might find it useful, as I've found my way here too.

### Method 1: NumberFormat

```java
double value = 1234.5678;

NumberFormat formatter1 = new DecimalFormat("##.0");
String text1 = formatter1.format(value); // "1234.6"

NumberFormat formatter2 = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
String text2 = formatter2.format(value); // "1234.57"
```

Rounding approach is optionally configurable:

```java
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
// UP, DOWN, CEILING, FLOOR, HALF_UP, HALF_DOWN, HALF_EVEN, UNNECESSARY
```

Using this, we can modify the code a little bit to achieve the desired behavior:

```java
double value = 127.12;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
String output = (value == (int) value)
    ? Double.toString(value)
    : formatter.format(value);
```

This meets your requirements. One thing to mention, for `123.4` it returns `123.40`. If you'd like to prevent this, we can do the integer comparison with a shifted decimal dot:

```java
double value = 127.12;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
String output = (value * 10 == (int) (value * 10))
    ? Double.toString(value)
    : formatter.format(value);
```

This returns `"127.0"` for `127.000000`, `"0.0"` for `0.000000`, `"123.45"` for `123.456` and also `"123.4"` for `123.4`.

### Method 2: Simple Java

It's not the nicest way, but maybe the shortest? Previously I just did:

```java
double value = 1234.56789;
String text = Double.toString(Math.round(value * 10.0) / 10.0); // "1234.6"
```

Same with keeping at most 2 digits:

```java
double value = 1234.56789;
String text = Double.toString(Math.round(value * 100.0) / 100.0); // "1234.57"
```

This way we explicitly round the number to a desired precision. We can truncate it too:

```java
double value = 1234.56789;
String text = Double.toString(((int) (value * 10.0) / 10.0)); // "1234.5"
```

One could argue, that making a multiplication and a division is a waste of computational power, but I guess it's still faster than modifying the result string, removing trailing zeros, etc. Also, since floating points are stored in memory in binary format and not decimal, running `* 10.0 / 10.0` might not result the *exact same* number.